# I want to find functions in code files using eclipse API

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-api

I'm trying to search which API method can be used for finding the functions or methods present in a code file using Eclipse API.

trying to find relevant API method in eclipse API. Like if we use the specific method, it will return the function names present in the file.

Comment: You use the [Eclipse JDT Abstract Syntax Tree](https://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJDT/article.html) for that